# What are adjective phrases exactly?

Tags: grammatical-roles, adjectival-phrases, adverbial-phrases

I've been under the impression that "adverbial phrases" are phrases that function adverbially and "adjectival phrases" are phrases that function adjectivally. My understanding is PP and AdvP can overlap, and so can PP and AdjP. A prepositional phrase *could* be an adverbial phrase or adjectival phrase.

But information on Wikipedia is contradictory in this regard. The [Wikipedia page for "Adjective phrase"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase) says: (by the way, that page is slightly messy, possibly vandalized)

> An adjective phrase (or adjectival phrase) is a phrase the head of which is an adjective

Per this definition, adjective phrases are defined in much a similar way to noun phrases and prepositional phrases. However, another Wikipedia page has this line:

> She's [*the woman **with the hat***]. (adjectival phrase, in this case a prepositional phrase, modifying a noun in a noun phrase)  ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier))

Clearly "with the hat" is a prepositional phrase with no adjective head. So which definition is correct? Can prepositional phrases also be adjectival phrases?

Comment: Wikipedia mentions that sometimes there is a division between "adjective phrase" and "adjectival phrase" with the former having an adjective as the head and the latter not, but both modifying nouns. However, this claim isn't referenced at all, so I'm not sure if it's widespread. (Certainly I'd share your view that a prepositional phrase can be adjectival.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase#Adjective_vs._adjectival

Comment: **No**, PPs can't be AdjPs. Your confusing form and function.  An adjective phrase is one whose head word is an adjective, as in "I have a [very **nice**] teacher". An adverb phrase is one whose head word is an adverb, as in "He was wounded [almost **fatally**]". And a preposition phrase is one whose word is a preposition , as in "We left [**before** the last act]".How such phrases function is another matter. For example in my first example "very nice" is an adjective phrase and its function is **modifier**. @StuartF Please note.

Comment: @BillJ There is still the assumption that CGEL analyses and terminology (preferable as they often might be) are accepted and used by all authorities. ELU welcomes _debate_.

Comment: @StuartF Thanks. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks. This helps. It's not so much I confused form and function. I was aware that those were two different things. Lack of consistency among Wiki articles bothers me no end. There is no Wiki page on "adverb phrase" and "adverb phrase" redirects to ["*adverbial phrase*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase) which maintains "AdvP is a multi-word expression operating adverbially". So are you saying there is no such distinction between "adjective phrase" and "adjectival phrase", or between "adverb phrase" and "adverbial phrase"? And is that Wiki article mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

The confusion stems from calling anything that modifies a noun an adjective, and the only slightly better solution of saying 'adjectival' instead of 'modifier in a noun phrase'.

The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar p9

> adjectival (n. & adj.) Loosely, (a word, phrase, or clause) behaving
> like an adjective (including single-word adjectives); e.g. in a *damp
> cloth*, the word *damp* is an adjectival element.
>
> The term is also used for examples like the following:
>
> *guide* price
>
> the *greenhouse* effect
>
> the man *in the white suit*
>
> an *I’m-all-right-Jack* attitude
>
> Some writers informally use the word adjectival to describe all of the
> italicized strings (or even say that they are adjectives), but this is
> infelicitous, since form and function are being confused: the first
> two examples involve nouns as modifiers; the third example involves a
> prepositional phrase; and the final example has a clause as modifier.
> Note that the terms adjectival and adverbial are not entirely
> comparable. Adverbial can denote one of the main elements (1) in
> clause structure (the others being subject, verb, object, and
> complement); it is then a function label. Adjectivals operate at a
> lower level, often as part of a noun phrase (which itself may function
> as subject or object). An adjectival may in some instances be the sole
> realization of a complement (e.g. You look *hungry*), but the adjectival
> as such is not a functional element in clause structure.

In modern grammar form and function are treated separately. Adjective phrases, noun phrases, prepositional phrases and so on are defined based on their internal structure, and the range of possible functions they can fulfill in larger constructions. Any particular instance of a phrase has a specific function: subject, object, modifier, complement, etc.

Comment: 'In modern grammar form and function are treated separately' seems to be your summary here. It neatly glosses over the fact that there are various competing grammars. Have you a supporting reference claiming that the 'some writers' mentioned don't include respected grammarians?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For those who insist on meting out grammatical relations labels in terms of parts of speech or phrase category labels, there simply is no defensible position, apart from “that’s the way it’s been done in the past’. There’s no defending wild and unprincipled ambiguity in one’s terminology.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. What would be your preference for labelling, then? And who should enforce the rigorously defensible positions against unprincipled terminological ambiguity? Seems to me this is asking for pure distilled water in the middle of the Pacific Ocean.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Consider the example “I saw her this morning”. Here “this morning” is an NP: NPs typically function as subjects or objects (complements), but in this example “this morning" is functioning as an adjunct. And consider this example “The only way that this can be resolved is if you accept some of Ed's suggestions”. “If you accept some of Ed’s suggestions” is a PP, and PPs typically function as adjunct, but they don’t invariably function that way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth cont ... “Be” requires a complement ((leaving aside the case of ellipsis, which is not relevant here), so the "if" PP must have that function here. This is why the distinction between function and category (or class) is so important.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Further, consider a comparable example with "because", which likewise introduces the complement of "BE"
A. "I wasn't invited to his party!".
B. "That's because his mother doesn't like you."
"Because" usually introduces adjuncts, but here the PP "because his mother doesn't like you" can only be complement.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for considerable justification of the stance taken by the answer, but which the answer fails to provide.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have no particular preference for individual bits of terminology, nor a penchant for rigorously defensible bits of terminology. However, I do prefer terminology that doesn't seem to be almost designed to create problematic ambiguity. You could label word categories with astrological symbols and grammatical relations with chemical symbols. No complaint from me. But if someone uses the same symbols for specific word categories and then also other specific grammatical relations, that's a pain in the posterior, because no-one knows what they're referring to.

Comment: @JohnLawler Imagine if one did that kind of thing in medicine! Why should we want to be deliberately confusing?